# mod_rewrite rule to work with get method

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, get, methods, rule

I'm using this rule:

```
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ public/$1    [L]
```

and in public folder I use:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

when I try to acess something on url using slash or it works fine and I get:

```
/cities/display/45   =>   Array ( [0] => cities [1] => display [2] => 45)
```

But when I try to submit a form, i'm not able to acces the data:

```
/cities/?field1=value1&field2=value2   =>   Array ( [0] => cities)
```

How can I solve this? I need a rule that also gets form's submited values

Thanks

Comment: How do you process the requested URI?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like PHP-Code...

Why aren't you accessing the form submitted values via $_GET['field1'] or $_REQUEST['field1'] ?